# LibGDX вращение объекта за курсором мыши

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, mouse-event

Не нашел нужного метода по реализации вращения объекта за курсором мыши. Пытался сам реализовать это, но в связи с неопытностью, этого сделать не вышло. Само вращение осуществляю через метод draw класса SpriteBatch.

Comment: Вам нужно чтото типа передвижения мышкой прицела? Телом вращения выступает пушка?

Comment: Тело вращения - это круг и прямоугольник (все в единой картинке, центр которой является центр круга, прямоугольник - это пушка). Что-то похожее на Diep.io.

Comment: Блин сегодня на парах писал игру на макромедиа. Скажу что нужно получать координаты мыши и что то делать с ним там класс Math задействуется

Answer (score 2):

Что нужно сделать:
1. Определить координаты мыши на экране
2. Преобразовать эти координаты в игровые (3D пространство) на плоскости где находится ваш объект.
3. Построить вектор от вашего объекта до мыши
4. С помощью вектора найти угол через `Math.atan2();`
5. Повернуть ваш объект на требуемый угол.

Если нужен будет конкретный пример, пишите в комментарии. Обновлю сообщение.

Comment: Я сделал так... Но т.к. вращение осуществляется каждый кадр, я решил сохранять предыдущие координаты курсора мышки и вращать объект на угол, заключенный между векторами, у которых координаты концов равны координатам предыдущего положения курсора мышки и нынешнего. И тут возникла проблема: объект в игре может двигаться, и если он движется, и курсор стоит на месте, то объект не вращается, и при дальнейшем движении курсора объект начинает вращаться косо.

Comment: Не нужно оптимизировать там, где это не требуется. Лучше каждый кадр считайте угол и вращайте, если он изменился. Если по какой-либо причине (в чём я сомневаюсь) будет тормозить, то можно выделить расчёт в другой поток. Можно ещё кидать события на движение мыши и движение объекта. И только при их наступлении проводить вращение.